# Android: how to have my app open automatically?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Basically I want my app to start running in the background when the ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON is clicked. I've seen other apps do this, so it must be possible. I just don't know how it is possible. Some kind of special manifest code?

Currently my app can receive intents from the ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON when it has been opened (and even running in the background) via intentfilter that I register in Java code of the main activity (when the app is first opened). But how would I have this button just... open up the app?

For reference, the following app can already do this functionality: https://market.android.com/details?id=com.kober.headset

Much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Are you listening for the intent in your manifest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `BroadcastReceiver` and register for the intent. See this [Android Developers Blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/06/allowing-applications-to-play-nicer.html) for more details.

Comment: thanks, I've already registered broadcast receivers and all that. The issue is I want the app to be able to open thru the button causing the ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON intent when the app is already closed, much like the headset button controller app I linked to.

Comment: Assuming you've properly registered your intent filter for that receiver in your manifest as that post describes, I don't see why it wouldn't work. Make sure you have it set in your manifest.

Comment: Setting it in the Manifest has done the trick! Thank you very much.